# Replacing ProxyPass with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I hit a known bug in Apache where if you use a very long hostname in a ProxyPass directive, it results in an error.  The suggested workaround is to replace the ProxyPass with a RewriteRule.  I am having a hard time getting a RewriteRule to work.  This is what my ProxyPass looked like:

```
ProxyPass /_plugin/kibana https://long-aws-hostname/_plugin/kibana   timeout=300
ProxyPassReverse /_plugin/kibana https://long-aws-hostname/_plugin/kibana   timeout=300
```

How would you rewrite that using a RewriteRule?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

```
<Proxy balancer://ServiceCoreCluster>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:7080
    # Add more BalanceMember if Service is present in different host
    # BalancerMember http://<hostname>:<port>
</Proxy>
.
.
.

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule "^/_plugin/kibana$" "balancer://ArgusCoreCluster/https://long-aws-hostname/_plugin/kibana" [P,L]
```

Add above lines, if you have already configured balancer just add last 2 lines (replacing with your lines).